# Node.js method does not return any response, pending request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Simple upload method using node.js+express.js:

```
upload: function(req, res, next){
    //go over each uploaded file
    async.each(req.files.upload, function(file, cb) {
        async.auto({
            //create new path and new unique filename
            metadata: function(cb){
                //some code...
               cb(null, {uuid:uuid, newFileName:newFileName, newPath:newPath});
            },
            //read file
            readFile: function(cb, r){
               fs.readFile(file.path, cb);
            },
            //write file to new destination
            writeFile: ['readFile', 'metadata', function(cb,r){
                fs.writeFile(r.metadata.newPath, r.readFile, function(){
                    console.log('finished');
                });   
            }]
        }, function(err, res){
            cb(err, res);
        });
    }, function(err){
        res.json({success:true});
    });

   return;
}
```

The method iterates each uploaded file, creates a new filename and writes it to a given location set in metadata.

```
console.log('finished');
```

is fired when writing is finished, however the client never receives a response. After 2 minutes the request is cancled, however the file was uploaded.

### Any ideas why this method does not return any response?

Comment: Because this is #1 in Google for a request gone pending in node, I'll mention that failure to get a response terminated can sometimes cause the *next* request to go pending. That makes for a helluva tedious debugging session, so now my top-level request handler always ends with `assert(response.finished)` so when the "can't happen" actually happens, I'm pointed at the right culprit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `readFile`, which is async, too, and works like this:

```
fs.readFile('/path/to/file',function(e,data)
{
    if (e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
    console.log(data);//file contents as Buffer
});
```

I you could pass a reference to a function here, to take care of this, but IMO, it'd be way easier to simply use `readFileSync`, which returns the Buffer directly, and can be passed to `writeFile` without issues:

```
fs.writeFile(r.metadata.newPath, r.readFileSync, function(err)
{
    if (err)
    {
        throw err;
    }
    console.log('Finished');
});
```

Check the docs for [`readFile`](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_filename_options_callback) and [`writeFile`](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_filename_data_options_callback) respectively

Comment: readFileSync is not working, because it has no callback paramter. If I add return res.json(..) to writeFile callback it works.  But the code from my question should work like it is...

Comment: @artworkadシ: You don't pass a callback to it, you just use its return value, which is a buffer... no need for a callback: `fs.readFileSync(filePath)` is all it takes, or in a function `return fs.readFileSync(filePath);`. You're calling `readFile` (an async function) at the time you need the file contents, which isn't available yet. You're free to use IIFE's, but at some point, you're just going to have to wait for all data to be available, so use the synchronous function to begin with. K.I.S.(S.)

Comment: + _"Debugging is twice as hard as writing the code in the first place. Therefore, if you write the code as cleverly as possible, you are, by definition, not smart enough to debug it."_ — Brian Kernighan

Comment: When I do "fs.writeFile(r.metadata.newPath, fs.readFileSync(file.path), callback) the request is still pending. Any ideas?

Comment: Just how big a files are we talking about?

Comment: for now just some kb, say 60 kb

Comment: @artworkadシ: could you post the src of `cb`? Because I can't work out what its job actually is...

Comment: @artworkadシ: Still can't see `cb` being defined anywhere `console.log` it, or add `if (!cb){console.log('undef'); return;}`